# extjs textarea returns field value as an array

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm quite puzzled by this.

When I get my field values from my extjs form, the value for a textarea is not a string, but an array. The first element in the array is empty, and the second element contains the text in the textarea.

[image]

I am just calling **getFieldValues()** from my form like so :

```
var fields = form.getFieldValues();
```

My UI decleration looks like this :

```
{
  xtype: 'textarea',
  cls: 'packagedialog-information-textArea',
  name: 'description'
}
```

In my **Ext.data.Model** it looks like this :

```
{name: 'description', type: 'string'},
```

Is it supposed to work like that? I was expecting a string to be returned.

Comment: It isn't supposed to work like that. Have you made sure that the very same form does not contain a second field by the name 'description'? (but even if it does, it shouldn't return an array...)

Comment: yes, i just noticed i have two fields that are 'description' :) Thanks! You can add this comment as an answer and i will accept it